# IIS 7 Grant user permissions

Tags: iis, iis-7, permissions, asp.net, .net

I get the following error:

```
ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access 
rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process 
identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used   
if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via 
<identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically 
IUSR_MACHINENAME) orthe authenticated request user.
```

I have read that there is no ASPNET user in IIS 7. I have also added [Machine name]\IIS_IUSRS but still get the error. Which user do I need to add?

Comment: Is your application impersonating?

Comment: how do i tell that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably Network Service ​​​​